# Correct way to generate digital signature for string using pgp certificate and bouncy castle in java?

Tags: java, digital-signature, bouncycastle, pgp

I need to simply generate digital signature for a string value. I was trying to modificate [this](https://github.com/bcgit/bc-java/blob/master/pg/src/main/java/org/bouncycastle/openpgp/examples/PGPExampleUtil.java) example, but has no success trying to make it work for string value. I ended up using this code snippet:

```
    public static byte[] signData(byte[] data) throws Exception {
    Provider bouncyCastle = new org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider();
    PGPSecretKeyRingCollection secretKeyRings = new PGPSecretKeyRingCollection(new FileInputStream(new File("/path_to_binary.gpg")));
    PGPSecretKeyRing secretKeyRing = (PGPSecretKeyRing) secretKeyRings.getKeyRings().next();
    PGPSecretKey secretKey = (PGPSecretKey) secretKeyRing.getSecretKeys().next();
    PGPPrivateKey pgpPrivateKey = secretKey.extractPrivateKey(new JcePBESecretKeyDecryptorBuilder().setProvider(bouncyCastle).build("password".toCharArray()));
    PGPSignatureGenerator sGen = new PGPSignatureGenerator(new JcaPGPContentSignerBuilder(secretKey.getPublicKey().getAlgorithm(), PGPUtil.SHA1).setProvider(bouncyCastle));
    PGPSignatureSubpacketGenerator  spGen = new PGPSignatureSubpacketGenerator();
    sGen.init(PGPSignature.STAND_ALONE, pgpPrivateKey);
    Iterator userIDs = secretKey.getPublicKey().getUserIDs();
    if (userIDs.hasNext()) {
        spGen.setSignerUserID(false, (String)userIDs.next());
        sGen.setHashedSubpackets(spGen.generate());
    }
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    sGen.update(data);
    baos.write(data);
    sGen.generateOnePassVersion(false).encode(baos);
    baos.flush();
    baos.close();
    return baos.toByteArray();
}
```

And got this result (string representation):

`[B@50867e0f`

What is obviously not a digital signature. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: how do you know it is not a digital signature. signData method returns byte array. if you want its string representation you may encode that byte array. byte[] bytes = signData(data); String encoded = java.util.Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(bytes); System.out.println(encoded);

Comment: you should compare length's of bytes. `kA0DAgIBojClwALp6zEB` is only a string representation of your generated byte array.

Comment: Many thanks! The problem is when I try to sign using that exact key and regular gpg linux tool i get something more long, like this http://i.imgur.com/CTvTaNR.png
for the same value I get this result `QkZFQkZCRkYwMDAzMDZBOZANAwICAaIwpcAC6esxAQ==` at my software.

Comment: Running `echo 'QkZFQkZCRkYwMDAzMDZBOZANAwICAaIwpcAC6esxAQ==' | base64 --decode | hexdump -c`, this seems like a long key ID (64 bit hex value).